# Convert JSONObject to JSONArray

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

i am using this JSONParser.java:

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);            
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

it is working fine for my other requests.
Now my php-file sending an array.
How I convert it to an Jarray or directly in an ArrayList, which i can use in my app?

the array (2 items) looks like:

```
03-15 20:40:16.667: E/JSON(26100): [{"ean":"8029694000","name":"KRINGS-VERBAU","betriebsdatenalt":"412"},{"ean":"8026786937","name":"KOMPRESSOR FAHR  5,3 M3  XAS97DDG","betriebsdatenalt":"0"}]
```

Comment: Have you looked at http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html ?

Comment: As an aside I'd seriously reccomend looking at gson or jackson for dealing with json; the org.json library is not the most pleasant to work with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an array

```
      JSONArray myArray=new JSONArray(string)
```

now loop through the array and get the objects like

```
    ArrayList<JSONObject> yourObjects=new ArrayList<JSONObject>(); 
    for(int i=0;i<myArray.length();i++){
        yourObjects.add(myArray.getJSONObject(i))
    }
```

also check every time if its a object or array you are getting like if

```
     JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(string from server);
     if(obj==null){
         JSONArray array=new JSONArray(string from server)
     }
```